# Why TextFormField's onSaved method requires a nullable String?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, flutter-textformfield

**Minimum reproducible code:**

```dart
final GlobalKey<FormState> _globalKey = GlobalKey();
  
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: [
        Form(
          key: _globalKey,
          child: TextFormField(onSaved: (String? string) {}),
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => _globalKey.currentState!.save(),
          child: Text('Save'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Even if I don't enter anything (or bring this field in focus), clicking the `Save` button still gives me a non-null `String`. So, why does the `onSaved` requires a nullable `String?` in its parameter list i.e. why can't I do the following as `onSaved` always seems to have a non nullable value.

```dart
onSaved: (String string) {}, // Error
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you can leave the field empty. If the input type is for example numbers you can't convert an empty field to int.

Comment: Empty doesn't mean `null`. I know it can be empty but when can it be `null`, this is the question

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**
I think it's because of other form fields that aren't text.

Let's have a look at [`TextFormField`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField-class.html#instance-properties)s docs here, it says

> This is a convenience widget that wraps a `TextField` widget in a `FormField`.

So let's think of it as a composition of 2 parts `TextField` and `FormField`

So for an empty [`TextField`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html) the value is just an empty string, so the value can't be null AFAIK. that's why you'll find the [`onSubmitted`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/onSubmitted.html) attribute (in a `TextField` not a `TextFormField`) accepts `String`s as you'd expect;
because it's defined as a `final ValueChanged<String>? onSubmitted;`
which is `typedef ValueChanged<T> = void Function(T value);` (`T` in our case is `String`) so no nulls allowed!

But What about `TextFormField`? well now that `onSubmitted` attribute is called `onFieldSubmitted`, keep in mind this function has nothing to do with it being a `FormField` but rather a standalone `TextField`

What *we* want, is the function that is called when the whole `Form` is saved, which is `onSaved`, but this actually comes from the [`FormField`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormField-class.html) part.

as stated in another answer it is `FormFieldSetter<String>? onSaved,;`
but this time `typedef FormFieldSetter<T> = void Function(T? newValue);` note it's `T?` not `T` so nulls Are allowed!

**Why?**
I think because there are other types of `FormField` in which `null` makes sense (e.g. [`DropdownButtonFormField`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButtonFormField/DropdownButtonFormField.html)).
because values are not necessarily `String`s anymore, `null` is used to represent ... well, a null value :D

Answer (score -1):

[`onSaved`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormField/onSaved.html) is defined as `FormFieldSetter<String>? onSaved,`

And [`FormFieldSetter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FormFieldSetter.html) is

```dart
typedef FormFieldSetter<T> = void Function(T? newValue);
```

So it expects nullable datatype on callback

solution is

```dart
 onSaved: (String? string) {},
```

Comment: The question is why it is defined as `FormFieldSetter<String>` and not `ValueChanged<String>` when it will always have a non-nullable value.

Comment: This answer will be, decided by flutter, I can't say exact reason, you can ask on git issue and propose it.  I assume `ValueChanged` occurs on every Change, where `FormFieldSetter` sets only on submit, yes it could be empty string on `FormFieldSetter` too